# Circle stuck at top left hand corner of screen swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw a circle in SwiftUI at a constantly changing variable `poseEstimator.bodyparts[.leftshoulder]!.location` of type CGPoint on my View, and the end goal is that when the variable changes, I want the circle on the screen to move to the new coordinates stored in the variable.

I read up online on how to draw a circle in swiftUI and found out that you need to use the  `Circle()` class to draw a circle, so that's what I did, but for some reason, my circle is always stuck at top left hand corner of the screen(0.0, 0.0), and even when I change the `.position` property of the circle to  `CGPoint(0.5,0.5)`, the circle is still stuck at the exact same location as before.

This is my swiftUI view struct:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StickFigureView: View {    //declare the stickfigure for pose esimation as a swift view
    @ObservedObject var poseEstimator: PoseEstimator
    
    var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        if poseEstimator.bodyParts.isEmpty == false { //add in the sticks only if there are VNPoints stored in "bodyparts"
            ZStack {
                
                // Right leg
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightAnkle]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightAnkle]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    .position(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)) // <- this is the circle which I have problems with
                
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightHip]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) {
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightHip]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                
                // Left leg
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftAnkle]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftAnkle]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftHip]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftHip]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                
                
                // Right arm
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightWrist]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightWrist]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightWrist]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightShoulder]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                
                // Left arm
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftWrist]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftWrist]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftShoulder]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    dot(Position: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), Color: Color.blue)
                        .position(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
                }
                // Root to nose
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Stick(points: [poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location,
                                   poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location], size: size)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
                
                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: 0.5 is half a point — are you sure you’d be able to tell if it had moved that much? That’d be one pixel on most retina screens and may not even render as a difference on a non retina or scaled display.

Comment: View coordinate space has "points" dimension, not percents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've finally cracked the code. @jnpdx was right, the CGPoint that I set was too small to be even rendered in the first place. Upon further troubleshooting, I found out that the variable `poseEstimator.bodyparts[.leftshoulder]!.location` that I assigned to the position property of the circle was around 0.3, which was too small to be seen. I had to scale the variable using `CGAffineTransform` so that the CGpoint was relative to the width and height of the screen. This fixed the problem.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct dotview: View {    //declare the stickfigure for pose esimation as a swift view
    @ObservedObject var poseEstimator: PoseEstimator
    
    var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        if poseEstimator.bodyParts.isEmpty == false { //add in the sticks only if there are VNPoints stored in "bodyparts"
            ZStack {
                // Right leg
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightAnkle]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightanklecolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightAnkle]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightkneecolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightHip]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightkneecolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightKnee]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.righthipcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightHip]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                // Left leg
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftAnkle]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftanklecolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftAnkle]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftkneecolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    
                }
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftHip]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftkneecolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftKnee]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.lefthipcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftHip]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                
                // Right arm
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightWrist]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightwristcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightWrist]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightelbowcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightShoulder]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightelbowcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightElbow]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rightshouldercolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.rightShoulder]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                // Left arm
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftWrist]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftwristcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftWrist]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftelbowcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftShoulder]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftelbowcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftElbow]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.leftshouldercolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.leftShoulder]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                // Root to nose
                if poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0) && poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location != CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.rootcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.root]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(poseEstimator.neckcolor)
                        .position(poseEstimator.bodyParts[.neck]!.location.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))            .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height)))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }
                
                
                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```